# How do I use an excerpt from Eleventy's gray-matter?

Tags: javascript, yaml-front-matter, eleventy

### Goal: Display a post excerpt for each post in the post list of an Eleventy blog

I'm adapting [this starter project](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog) as my own blog.
I'm referring to [this Eleventy document](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-frontmatter-customize/)
to get the post excerpt.

### My code:

I started by editing my *.eleventy.js* to enable gray-matter excerpt, per the above document, like so:

```js
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(pluginRss);
  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(pluginSyntaxHighlight);
  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(pluginNavigation);

  eleventyConfig.setDataDeepMerge(true);
  eleventyConfig.setFrontMatterParsingOptions({ excerpt: true
                                              });
  /* file continues below */
```

Next, I added "---" following the first paragraph in some blog posts, per the example.

Finally, I updated */_includes/postslist.njk* to include a reference to the excerpt for each post, so my new file now reads:

```html
<ol reversed class="postlist" style="counter-reset: start-from {{ (postslistCounter or postslist.length) + 1 }}">
{% for post in postslist | reverse %}
  <li class="postlist-item{% if post.url == url %} postlist-item-active{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ post.url | url }}" class="postlist-link">{% if post.data.title %}{{ post.data.title }}{% else %}<code>{{ post.url }}</code>{% endif %}</a>
    <time class="postlist-date" datetime="{{ post.date | htmlDateString }}">{{ post.date | htmlDateString }}</time>
    {% for tag in post.data.tags %}
      {%- if collections.tagList.indexOf(tag) != -1 -%}
      {% set tagUrl %}/tags/{{ tag }}/{% endset %}
      <a href="{{ tagUrl | url }}" class="tag">{{ tag }}</a>
      {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
    {%- if post.excerpt -%}
        <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
    {%- endif -%}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

but no excerpts appear.

### What I've Tried

I've checked for empty paragraph tags in the output HTML, and they are not there, so the `if`
condition itself is failing.

I've tried setting the excerpt separator to something other than the default
"---", with the same result.

Importantly, I've tried disabling excerpts in the *.eleventy.js*, which causes the separator to
be read as regular markdown. This is important because it shows that gray-matter is correctly
reading my separators in the blog posts as separators, **and therefore the problem must be in my
*/_includes/postslist.njk*.**

### Conclusion

How do I reference the excerpt that Eleventy generates from gray-matter?

(P. S.: I don't have enough reputation to create a StackOverflow tag for the `gray-matter` npm package, but imho it wouldn't be a bad idea if somebody wanted to do that. I've tagged it with
yaml-front-matter, which isn't wholly inaccurate, but as I understand it my issue is pretty
specific to the `gray-matter` dialect of yaml front matter. )

Comment: Further information: full source available at https://gitlab.com/webbureaucrat/webbureaucrat.gitlab.io

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the documentation, eleventy makes the excerpt available under the `page` variable (see [Eleventy supplied data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-eleventy-supplied/#page-variable-contents)), not as a 'top-level' property of a collection item. The `page` variable is part of the `data` object of a collection item. If you use `post.data.page.excerpt` instead of `post.excerpt` it will work as expected:

```
{%- if post.data.page.excerpt -%}
    <p>{{ post.data.page.excerpt }}</p>
{%- endif -%}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [excerpt_alias option](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-frontmatter-customize/#changing-where-your-excerpt-is-stored) to make the excerpt available as a top-level property. With this configuration, your template will work as is:

```
eleventyConfig.setFrontMatterParsingOptions({
    excerpt: true,
    excerpt_alias: 'excerpt',
});
```

Comment: Upvoted for effort, especially for the page variable info page, which I hadn't seen, but I couldn't get either config to work, unfortunately. I've forked a minimal example here: https://gitlab.com/eleanorofs/excerpt-example

Comment: @EleanorHolley Sorry, I messed up the first example. You need `post.data.page.excerpt` instead of `post.page.excerpt`. I've corrected that in the example code. In your minimal example, you put the `eleventyConfig.setFrontMatterParsingOptions` call *inside* the callback for the `tagList` collection, this is probably why the other option wasn't working. If you move that outside the callback it should work!

Comment: @EleanorHolley With the changes in this patch the excerpt ist working for me in your minimal example: https://gist.github.com/MoritzLost/50317d240101c870f41e035281dad51b